# How do I create recurring events in 4.6?

Tags: civievent

I am using CiviCRM 4.6.8 and I don't find the new ([supposedly since 4.6](https://civicrm.org/blogs/kurund/announcing-civicrm-46-release)) recurring events feature. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Gabor,  did you upgrade or is this a new install?  You should be a "repeat' tab when configuring an event.    For an example see the demo site:  http://d46.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/event/manage/settings?reset=1&action=update&id=3

Comment: Thanks, I was trying to find it on the first page of the event creation workflow. Now I see I have to add it first and then configure recurrence.

Answer (score 4):

Combining the question's comments into an answer:

The Repeat tab isn't available until the event has been saved. Create the event and save it, and you'll see the tab.